# Plotting json file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I'm trying to figure out how to plot a json file with pandas/plotly. The recieved output looks like this from the api[image]

with the following code:
`df=pd.read_json('https://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/mpk100/JSONSTAT?valuePresentation=Value&timeOrder=Ascending&LAND=*&Tid=*') df`

the code for plotting i use:

```
fig = px.line(df, x=df['dimension_time'], y=df['dimension_LAND'])
fig.show()
```

it gives me the following error:

```
KeyError: 'dimension_time'
```

i just really don't know how to pull data correctly for plotting. The data is commonly time series.

Comment: You have to know the key to access it. For example, df['dataset']['dimension'] ['LAND']

Comment: Hi, so is there a easy way to look up the variables that is available for plotting? i want fig = px.line(df, x=df['dataset']['dimension'] ['Tid'], y=df['dataset']['dimension'] ['Value']) showing the different values of interest rates over time for different countries. But this does not give any output

Comment: The value is in df['dataset']['value']. It has many values.

Comment: Your data is multidimensional.  Why don't you try csv instead? It is much simpler.

Comment: pd.read_csv('https://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/mpk100/CSV?valuePresentation=Value&timeOrder=Ascending
    ...: &LAND=*&Tid=*', sep=';')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('https://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/mpk100/CSV?valuePresentation=Value&timeOrder=Ascending&LAND=*&Tid=*', sep=';')
df = df[df['INDHOLD'] != '..']
df['rate'] = df['INDHOLD'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
df.groupby('LAND').plot(x='TID', y='rate')
plt.show()
```

Plot on the same chart:

```
df.pivot_table(index='TID', columns='LAND', values='rate').plot()   
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I really appreciate your help. So is it better to use csv rather than Json?  Do the csv file update when new values are added in the future?

Comment: It is the same API call. The only different is the output format.

Comment: Thank you! regarding the plot in the example. Is it possible to get it in one figure instead?

Comment: See the code above.